# PDO implementation issue in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to know why does this code work:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=university;charset=utf8","root","",
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
```

while this one doesn't:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host = localhost;dbname=university;charset = utf8","root","");
```

I have problem on that `utf8` section. Second code showed me ??? as result but first one worked properly.
Both should work properly but...

Comment: because `mysql:host = localhost;` and `charset = utf8` contains spaces if that's your actual/read code. There should not be any. Using exceptions would have signaled that. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: yes yes,problem was for spaces! ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference are the spaces near the two "=".

You need to erase them.

Comment: [Yeah, I said that...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141601/pdo-implementation-issue-in-php#comment50293792_31141601). Let's hope this one doesn't bite back. ;-)

Comment: Yes on my actualisation it weren't shown, sorry. I took a lot of time to say it in the minimum caracters :/